# Prob. 5, Sec. 25 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Is there a connected set that is locally connected at none of its points?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ denote the rational points of the interval $[0,1] \times 0$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T$ denote the union of all line segments joining the point $p = 0 \times 1$ to points of $A$.

Then I can show that $T$ is path-connected.

How to show rigorously that $T$ is locally connected only at the point $p$?

Can we find a space $X$ that is path-connected but is locally connected at noen of its points?

The set $T$ can be written as follows: 
$$T \ = \ \{ \ (tq, 1-t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}, \ t \in [0,1] \ \}.$$
Am I right?

For the point $p$, let 
$$U \ = \  B(p; \delta) \ = \ \{ \ (\xi, \eta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ \xi^2 + (\eta -1)^2 < \delta^2 \ \}.$$
Let $x$, $y \in U \cap T$. Then $x$ can be joined by a path in $T$ to the point $p$, which in turn can be joined to the point $y$. Thus $x$ and $y$ can be joined by a path in $T$, showing that $U$ is path-connected and hence connected. Therefore $T$ is locally connected at $p$. Am I right?

Now let $a$ be any other point of $T$. Then if we choose $\delta >0$ to be so small that the point  $p$ is not in the circular neighborhood of $a$, then we need to show the existence of two non-intersecting line segments passing through this circular neighborhood in order to show it to be not connected. Am I right?

Intuitively, it is clear. How to show this analytically?

Comment: I think it's OK. It is rigorous enough for me. It is clear that, if $p$ is excluded from the small disk, then it contains nothing more than a whole bunch of small disjoint segments.